# Any documentation available for xe:objectData?

Tags: objectdatasource, xpages

It seems, that the objectData control can be used as a performance boost for an xpage application. I understand the basic idea behind, but still have trouble to get it to work properly.
Using a objectData as input for a repeat control avoids the unneccessary refresh of the repeat during a partial refresh that was triggered on another refreshId than the id for the repeat. But due to the cache mechanism in the objectData, the objectData is not refreshed during a partial refresh of the surrounding div for example. Setting the scope to request, objectData is refreshed, but the issue with partial refresh also refreshing datasources outside the refreshId occurs. 
A bit weird, I know, but I do not know, how to explain it better.

So is there any documentation or sample on how to use objectData? Found one sample in the JDBC sampleDb, but it did not help.

Comment: If you find any further information on this, please do share with us Ulrich - thank you.

Comment: Hint: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=594

Comment: @UlrichKrause - I wonder: why don't you use managed bean? You can call its update() in button, bind it via EL. Only caveat is need for faces-config update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the repeat/specific row use case, introduce Partial Execution (execMode="partial" / execId="foo") to complement the Partial Refresh of the row.  This will hone component tree execution to the row of interest and avoid redundant processing outside of the specified target area.

In terms of documentation for objectData, the best worked example is indeed within the XPagesJDBC.nsf sample database (JDBC_RowSetDatasource.xsp) - it succinctly demonstrates using this datasource as a delegate to create a specialized DataContainer object from the current "row" variable, and conversely managing the specialized saving of the DataContainer object during the save process.  Although this example handles the delegation of SQL processing for the current row, the same approach is applicable under many use cases (eg: one example, the underlying view could be a view of XML documents, where you need to delegate per row handling using the objectData datasource through a custom specialized XML processing object).